# Magento 1.8 emails not sending to customers after order is placed

Tags: magento-1.8, order-email

So recently my website hasn't been sending order confirmation emails to myself and my customers. I am lost with this and need some help. Has anyone else had this problem? Please help me out.

Comment: Start by looking at your log files. You'll need to provide more information in your question to receive an appropriate response here.

Comment: does it solved??

Answer (score -2):

have you set the cron job right? check the following link and try it out:
[how to set up a cron job](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job)